# ZF3 advanced routing - parent and child routes with action param

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-router

Using ZF3, I'd like to access URLs like :

```
/dossier/add
/dossier/edit/2
/dossier/edit/2/droit/add
/dossier/edit/2/droit/edit/3
...
```

Here is my routing config :

```
'dossier' => [
     'type' => Segment::class,
     'options' => [
         'route' => '/dossier[/][:action][/:dosid]',
         'constraints' => [
             'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
             'dosid' => '[0-9_-]*|b[0-9]+|all'
         ],
         'defaults' => [
             'controller' => Controller\DossierController::class,
             'action'     => 'add',
         ],
     ],
     'may_terminate' => true,
     'child_routes' => [
         'droit' => [
             'type' => Segment::class,
             'options' => [
                 'route' => '/droit[/][:action][/:droid]',
                 'constraints' => [
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                     'droid' => '[0-9_-]*|b[0-9]+|all'
                 ],
                 'defaults' => [
                     'controller' => Controller\DroitController::class,
                     'action'     => 'add',
                 ],
             ]
         ]
     ]
 ]
```

Both parent and child routes possess an "action" param.
This config is working fine when called directly (i.e. entering url "/dossier/edit/3/droit/delete/2" in browser).
However, building the URL using viewHelper Url :

```
$this->url('dossier/droit', ['action' => 'delete', 'dosid' => 3, 'droid' => 2]);
```

produces URL :

```
/dossier/delete/3/droit//2
```

while displaying the creation ("add") view, instead of URL :

```
/dossier/edit/3/droit/delete/2
```

From topic [Zf2 view helper URL child route with same params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036749/zf2-view-helper-url-child-route-with-same-params), I know I can create one child route per child action, hence getting rid of the second "action" param, but this doesn't seem quite right.

I can't help but wonder why would I be able to have both parent and child route of type Segment and still being stuck because there is no way to rename the "action" param without breaking ZF's way of routing URLs to controller methods.

Route "droit" has to be a child route of "dossier" since it needs the id of the dossier (and putting the dossier's id in a hidden input in the form seems like an even worse solution).

Am I missing something? Isn't there any better solution?

Comment: Have you thought about SRP (Single Responsibility Principle), the name says it all, to apply to routing & actions? If an action handles only a single route, e.g. "view", or "edit", or "droit add", then your route structure will expand, but be a hell of a lot more logical / maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure to understand, SRP seems to be basically what ZF does, each route level has its controller and each route action has its own matching method in the route controller. In DroitController I have methods such as addAction(), editAction(), deleteAction(). Are you saying I should have one controller per action? e.g. AddDroitController, EditDroitController, ...?

Comment: Both yes. For a few reasons. It holds true to SRP. It makes Controller classes handle a single responsibility (though the "action" is what is eventually executed, the Controller as a whole handles it). It makes Controller more lean (no need to inject "DroitForm" into \Droit\ViewController, no form is needed there). And lastly: it makes that you have to define your routes **_per action_**. Creating a clear structure without overlapping responsibilities.

Comment: I understand, even if in my case each action implementation is quite short, so that seems to be a little overkill. Thank you for your explanations. I guess there is any way to force ZF3 to distinguish the two "action" parameters one from each other anyway, so that doesn't leave a lot of possibilities.